# Unable to copy war to Google Bucket

Tags: java, maven, google-compute-engine

I am trying to copy the the snapshot from my google cloud instance to the google bucket.

Maven is being used to compiling the code into a snapshot and snapshot is available at the below location -

/home/bhaskarhnarula/getting-started-java/bookshelf/6-gce/bookshelf-6-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war

In my build file, in my build sh, I am giving the following copy command which is throwing CommandException as below -

```
CommandException: No URLs matched: target/bookshelf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

Below command is used for moving the snapshot to the cloud -

```
+ gsutil cp target/bookshelf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war gs://cloudpoc2bucket
```

Aim is to host a sample application on a new instance created in Google Cloud via Google-Compute-Engine. Any leads would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No clue if you figured it out, but I ran into the same issue and found out that there was a typo in the script in the example; `target/bookshelf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` doesn't exist, it's actually called `target/bookshelf-6-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`. The error makes complete sense then, since the script's asking `gsutils` to upload a non-existent file. So if you look in the `makeBookshelf` script, you should see a line labeled

```
WAR=bookshelf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

it should actually be

```
WAR=bookshelf-6-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

Edit that and it should run perfectly fine.

I've already sent in a pull request to get this fixed in the repository. Hope you figured it out!